# Recovering a broken subversion repository?

Tags: svn, data-recovery

Due to a failing harddrive on my windows homeserver where my personal subversion repository resided im having some missing repository files (the files in db/revs/n/nnnn), and thus my checkins/checkouts are failing…

Is there any hope of recreating those files in any way or am i going to have to hope i got everything recently checked out somewhere and start over loosing the versionlog?

Comment: I know this isnt hugely helpful for the immediate issue, but due to a similar issue i moved to using bzr in a dstributed mode. It takes a little while to adapt, but its alot better when the central server runs into problems as each checkout can become a new server for others with only a few commands.

Comment: yes, i'm considering moving over to some more distributed system but havent gotten around to it yet, this seems like a good time to start..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you not take backups of the subversion folders (i.e. with a dump or just file backups)?  If not, and you're missing certain revisions, your best bet is to start making sure you have backed up copies of your last checkout.  This is a far better option than hoping that you can piece together a valid revision from what's left in the repository.